# Efficient pagination with column ordering in MySQL with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I'm implementing pagination without using `OFFSET` and I want to add a column ordering feature.

In my API, I want to get the pagination results by specifying:

- Previous ID (`prev_id`)
- Column to order by (`id`, `name`, `date`, `size`)
- Direction (`asc`, `desc`)

My query to get results ordered by `name` in `desc` order is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM uploads
WHERE user_id = $user_id
AND (name <= (SELECT name FROM uploads WHERE id = $prev_id))
AND ((name < (SELECT name FROM uploads WHERE id = $prev_id)) OR (id <= $prev_id))
ORDER BY name DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

It works, but it includes two identical subqueries. How can I avoid that? Will it actually run two subqueries or will it somehow optimize it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your identical subqueries will both get executed, but they carry very little overhead, as it is just a single row read from the clustered index. You could use the subquery as a derived table:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM uploads u
JOIN (SELECT name FROM uploads WHERE id = $prev_id) v
WHERE u.user_id = $user_id
AND (u.name <= v.name)
AND ((u.name < v.name) OR (u.id <= $prev_id))
ORDER BY u.name DESC, u.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```